# Regular Expression Multiple Options Character Exclusion

Tags: .net, regex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxISt.png)
We have the following regular expression `^(?<tloption>.*)>(?<Option>.*)$`  to match our string `Active Projects>Project Name 2022101`. We are trying to have the Option match all of the values except the last 8 characters.

We are using regex101: build, test, and debug regex to try to find a solution and are unable to.

We tried the following scripts without success

```
^(?<tloption>.*)>(?<Option>[a-z]*)$
^(?<tloption>.*)(?<Option>.*(?<!\d{8}))$
^(?<tloption>[^\d]*)(?<Option>[^\d]*(?<!\d{8}))$
```

Comment: Then consume the chars outside of the capturing group - `^(?<tloption>.*)>(?<Option>.*).{8}$`. Or, if the idea is to "unmatch" space + digits at the end - `^(?<tloption>.*)>(?<Option>.*)\s+\d+$`

Comment: Or the last 7 digits and leading whitespace chars after the last group `^(?<tloption>.*)>(?<Option>.*?)\s+\d{7}$`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
^(?<tloption>.*)>(?<Option>.*)(.{8})$
```